# How do I save a custom entity in the Sensenet database?

Tags: entity, sensenet

I'm trying to save a custom entity in the Sensenet database with an api call.

1. How do I create the model in the Sensenet database? Preferably in the ASP.NET project or with an api call from the front-end.
2. What url do I `POST` the entity to, to save it in the model I just created?

---

Here is the Angular TypeScript entity I want to save:

```
export class PersonEntity {
  public name: string;
  public email: string;
}
```

At first this will only be two text fields, to keep it simple. Later on I'd like to add an image too.

Comment: Which components of sensenet have you installed? Only _Services_, or do you have _WebPages_, the UI layer?

Comment: Both Services and WebPages. I'm running `SenseNet 7.0.0`, running it with `ASP.NET 5.2.3` and I'm trying to run an api call from an Angular (Typescript) application. I followed [this tutorial](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/install-sn-from-nuget/) for installing Sensenet and used [this tutorial](https://github.com/SenseNet/sn-webpages/blob/master/docs/install-webpages-from-nuget.md) for installing WebPages.

Comment: This deserves a proper, detailed answer, or better yet: a tutorial with steps. But for now I can point you to this one, as a starter:
http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_a_Content_Type
This is only about _creating the content type on the server side_. About _generating a client-side TS class_ from that type, there is another article, we should add that link too.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Somehow I didn't get to that page yet. I'll go check it out. I think it will solve question 1 and I'll probably be able to figure out question 2 once I have question 1 answered. If I solve it, I'll post an answer below.